# how to unpivot large AWS Redshift table

Tags: amazon-redshift, unpivot

I am trying to run a query against a table in AWS Redshift (i.e., postgresql).  Below is a simplified definition of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE some_schema.some_table (
    row_id int
    ,productid_level1 char(1)
    ,productid_level2 char(1)
    ,productid_level3 char(1)
)
;

INSERT INTO some_schema.some_table
VALUES
    (1, a, b, c)
    ,(2, d, c, e)
    ,(3, c, f, g)
    ,(4, e, h, i)
    ,(5, f, j, k)
    ,(6, g, l, m)
;
```

I need to return a de-duped, single column table of a given productid and all of its children.  "Children" means any productid that has "level" higher than the given product (for a given row) and also its grandchildren.

For example, for productid 'c', I expect to return...

- 'c' (because it's found in rows 1, 2, and 3)
- 'e' (because it's a child of 'c' in row 2)
- 'f' and 'g' (because they're children of 'c' in row 3)
- 'h' and 'i' (because they're children of 'e' in row 4)
- 'j' and 'k' (because they're children of 'f' in row 5)
- and 'l' and 'm' (because they're children of 'g' in row 6)

Visually, I expect to return the following:

```
productid
---------
c
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
```

The actual table has about 3M rows and has about 20 "levels".

I think there are 2 parts to this query -- (1) a recursive CTE to build out the hierarchy and (2) an unpivot operation.

I have not attempted (1) yet.  For (2), I have tried a query like the following, but it hasn't returned even after 3 minutes.  As this will be used for an operational report, I need it to return in < 15 seconds.

```
select
    b.productid
    ,b.product_level
from
    some_schema.some_table as a
cross join lateral (
    values
    (a.productid_level1, 1)
    ,(a.productid_level2, 2)
    ...
    ,(a.productid_level20, 20)
) as b(productid, product_level)
```

How can I write the query to achieve (1) and (2) and be very performant?

Comment: Redshift is designed around denormalised wide tables. That's most efficient for its use as a reporting platform *(it's for OLAP, not OLTP)*. So, why do you want a structure the platform is not optimised for? *(Also, RedShift forked from PostgreSQL, but it has significantly diverged. Redshift **is not** PostgreSQL.)*

Comment: For a given product, I need to determine all of its children products.  Despite the column names, they don't give me the complete hierarchy.  So, I was attempting to do what I always do with denormalized tables -- unpivot them and build out the hierarchy via a recursive CTE.  Perhaps there is a way that I can do it by leaving it denormalized.

Comment: You say this runs in Redshift?  I don't think Redshift supports "lateral" in the FROM clause.  Can you confirm this is now supported?  I see no reference to it in the latest docs.  As for performing this operation you should look at the UNPIVIOT capability of the FROM clause of Redshift.  As far as I know this only works on a single output column but you should be able to work around this.

Comment: Yes, this runs in Redshift.  In fact, I first tried to use the UNPIVOT keyword, but Redshift threw an error.  So, I'm encountering the opposite of you.

Comment: This is increasingly sounding like an XY Problem. Instead of asking us to improve the performance of your solution to your problem, ask for alternative solutions to your problem. Shown us an example of the type of data you are starting with, describe why it is insufficient for your requirements, and what precisely you're trying to achieve (not what layout you *want*, but the functional need you're trying to address).

Comment: @skyline01 As Redshift certainly supports UNPIVOT, all your error means is that your code has a mistake.

Comment: @MatBailie I have updated my post as requested.

Comment: @MatBailie I have determined that UNPIVOT does indeed work.  I'm using Dbeaver as my query client tool.  Dbeaver doesn't display UNPIVOT in a different color (like I'm used to in SSMS).  Also, it turns out that the error I was seeing was due to table aliases.  For some reason, an unpivot operation doesn't like table aliases.

Comment: Your table has 20 "levels" and that's still not enough depth to cover the whole hierarchy?

Comment: Is the fact that `c` is a child of both `b` and `d` intentional? Or should we assume each node can only have one parent, but many children?

Comment: Do your real data have overlaps? For example, could one row be ABCDEFG and another row be ABCDXYZ? (Thus part of the hierarchy path that is ABCD is repeated on more than one row?)

Comment: Are all 20 columns always populated? Or is it sparsely populated? Such as NULL NULL A B C D or perhaps A B C D NULL NULL?

Comment: Yes, 20 levels is not enough depth.  It's not a well-designed table, and it's very complicated to explain what it represents.  Yes, c is a child of both b and d.  Yes, the real data has overlaps.  The "level" columns are sparsely populated.  But, it will always be left-ragged, never right-ragged (i.e., it will always be like A B C NULL ..., never like NULL A B C).

Comment: I'm almost wondering if this is an impossible ask.  Perhaps I should ask the data engineers responsible for this to create a new pipeline for me that will output a table in the desired format and in the proper storage technology (i.e., not Redshift).  I shouldn't be using an OLAP (dimensional) table for operational reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using the term Hierarchy, as that "usually" implies any node having a single parent at most.

I admit I'm lost as to the nature of the graph/network this table represents. But you ***might*** benefit from a little brute force and code repetition.

Whatever eventually works for you, I think you'll need to persist/materialise/cache the results, as repeating this at report time is unlikely to ever be a good idea.

I'm a data engineer by trade, and I'm sure they have good reasons for what they've done (or, like me, they maybe screwed up). Either way, there are many good reasons to ask them to materialise the graph in more than just one form, each suited to different use cases.  So, asking them for a traditional adjacency list, *as well as* the table you already have, is a reasonable request. Or, at the very least, a good starting point for a conversation.

So, a brute force approach?

```
WITH
  adjacency AS
(
  SELECT level01, level02 FROM some_table WHERE level02 IS NOT NULL
  UNION
  SELECT level02, level03 FROM some_table WHERE level03 IS NOT NULL
  UNION
  ...
  UNION
  SELECT level19, level20 FROM some_table WHERE level20 IS NOT NULL
)
```

The WHERE clause elimates any sparse data before it enters the map.

The UNION (without ALL) ensures duplicate links are eliminated. You should also test UNION ALL and then wrapping a SELECT DISTINCT around it (or similar).

Then you can use that adjacency list in the usual recursive walk, to find all children of a given node. (Taking care that there aren't any cyclic paths.)

Comment: If you do get a new table, I'd request a map of every node to every child, so as to avoid the recursive walk. So, an adjacency list of AB, AC, BD, BE, CF, CG would be materialised with every associated pair, regardless of the number of nodes between them; AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, AG, BC, BD, CF, CG

Comment: Inserting the adjacency list in to a table distributed by level01 and sorted by level01, level02 ***might*** give the engine a hint on how to remove duplicates. BUT you should probably only use that as an intermediate step ; distributing the adjacency list like that may well cripple the recursive walk.